Can i access Tomorow date inside Query Template inside PnP Modern search web part
I have a Search Result web part which is part of PnP modern search web part. Now I have a RefinableDate00 managed property which is linked to a SharePoint site column of type DateOnly, now using the following Query Template inside the Search Result web part, I am able to get the items which have their RefianbleDate00 = today date:-
{searchTerms} 
ContentType:"Carrier" 
(RefinableDate00=today)

but i also want to build another Search Result web part which show the items which have their RefinableDate00 = Tomorrow. I tried this:-
{searchTerms} 
ContentType:"Carrier" 
(RefinableDate00=today+1)

but this did not return any items.. any advice ,, how i can get tomorrow date inside Query template?

With PnP Modern Search v4 the syntax is: {Today+1}
So this should work:
{searchTerms} ContentType:"Carrier" RefinableDate00={Today+1}

Source: Tokens - PnP Modern Search (v4)

{Today+/- <integer value for number of days>}
A date calculated by
adding/subtracting the specified number of days to/from the date when
the query is issued. Date format is YYYY-MM-DD (Ex: {Today+5})


i thought that should work , but it will not return any result even that i have items which match the criteria
